# Use wildcard in QBXML when integrating into quickbooks with web connector

Tags: php, xml, quickbooks, qbxml

I am trying to add charges into quickbooks via web connector from an online system. The names of the customer can be updated on each system and thus causes in-efficiencies in synchronization because the name of the customer is what is used in synchronization. Can the name of the customer use a format like, [customercode] * . Currently generating the following QBXML

```html
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <?qbxml version="10.0"?>
  <QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
  <ChargeAddRq requestID="9">
  <ChargeAdd>
  <CustomerRef>
  <FullName>123456 John Doe</FullName>
  </CustomerRef>
  <TxnDate></TxnDate>
  <RefNumber>11</RefNumber>
  <ItemRef>
  <FullName>SHOE</FullName>
  </ItemRef>
  <Quantity>4</Quantity>
  <Rate>50</Rate>
  <Desc> billing </Desc>
  </ChargeAdd>
  </ChargeAddRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
  </QBXML>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can *name* the customer whatever you want.

But you still need to refer to it by it's *exact name*. You can't just tell QuickBooks `<CustomerRef><FullName>Something *</FullName></CustomerRef>` and expect QuickBooks to match to `Something 1234` successfully.

If you're having trouble with people renaming the customers, then use the `ListID` values instead. They are unique, and the purpose of them is specifically so you can refer to customers that may have been renamed but still have that same unique `ListID` value which never changes.